# Separate subreports in worksheets with JasperXlsxExporterBuilder

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I would like to separate subreports in worksheets but if I setOnePagePerSheet(true) the second subreport, which is very long breaks also in multiple worksheets. I would like only one worksheet for each subreport.

These are my settings for the exporter:

```
        reportBuilder.title(cmp.subreport(criteriaReportBuilder), cmp.pageBreak(), cmp.subreport(secondReportBuilder));
JasperXlsxExporterBuilder xlsxExporter = DynamicReports.export.xlsxExporter(outputStream);
        xlsxExporter.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
        xlsxExporter.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
        xlsxExporter.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(false);
        xlsxExporter.setDetectCellType(true);
        xlsxExporter.setWhitePageBackground(false);
        xlsxExporter.setIgnoreGraphics(false);
        xlsxExporter.setOnePagePerSheet(true);
        xlsxExporter.setMaxRowsPerSheet(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        reportBuilder.toXlsx(xlsxExporter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set excel to break when you like it to not on every report page

```
xlsxExporter.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
```

add **property** `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row` to **reportElement** when you like it to break into new sheet

example

```
<reportElement x="7" y="15" width="146" height="35" uuid="8ee71878-fc35-4991-a7dc-5199f23f2978">
   <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row" value="true"/>
</reportElement>
```

Comment: I have no xml template for the main report. I tried with "cmp.pageBreak()" between the subreport (updated the example) but the pageBreak will be ignored

Comment: @knobli I have revised my answer, found a nice property in jasper report docs, I have test it and it works. In dynamic jasper you should be able to add this property.

Comment: Do you have also an code example? I found the property JasperProperty.EXPORT_XLS_BREAK_AFTER_ROW but I don't know, where I should set it

Comment: What object does cmp.subreport(secondReportBuilder) return, do you use templates (.jrxml) that you load or do you create all with Dynamic jasper?

Comment: I have only one Template for the criteriaReportBuilder, the others created by Dynamic jasper. The object that will be returned is SubreportBuilder

Comment: If you have a templete for criteriaReportBuilder set net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row on "last" reportElement (the one on the end of the page) as in example, remember to set xlsxExporter.setOnePagePerSheet(false);

Comment: Can't find any other quick way in DynamicJasper to set this property, work around would be 1) Generate mulitple reports 1 main, 1 sub reports ecc and export each one to a different sheet. 2) From DynamicJasper get the JasperReport object, find the reportElement set the property and then export to excel using the JasperReport object.

Comment: Thanks, I add a line element to the page footer of the criteria jrxml and it works. Maybe you have also a solution for my second problem goo.gl/kfw7QX